# Cant seem to get my Jbutton to lock. Error: Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

This is my source code for a tic tak toe game I am trying to make, what I would like to happen is for a player to press a Jbutton then have the button disabled.  I am aware that the command is setEnbale(false) in order for it to lock, but it is not working for me. I have 9 buttons with action listener assigned to them.  The program is able to distinguish between player 1 and 2 through the action listener.  But when I try to lock the cells as well the " error : can not find symbol some up. "  come up.  What exactlyam I doing wrong?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TicTacToe extends JFrame
{
private final int HEIGHT = 450;
private final int WIDTH = 500;
private static JButton [] button = new JButton[9];
private static Action [] playerTurn = new Action[9];
private static JLabel [] label;
private int player = 1;
private static int lockButtons = 0;

public TicTacToe ()
{
    setTitle( " Tic Tac Toe ");
    setSize( HEIGHT, WIDTH);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));

    int num = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
    {

        button[i] = new JButton( "B" + i + 1);
        playerTurn[i] = new Action();
        add(button[i]);
        button[i].addActionListener(playerTurn[i]);
    }


    setVisible(true);
}


private class Action implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent playerMove)
    {
        //Get button pressed using GetSource Command
        JButton whatPlayer=(JButton)(playerMove.getSource());

            if(player == 1)
            {
                player++;
                whatPlayer.setText("player1");
                whatPlayer.setEnable(false); // this is what is cause me the error
                return;
            }   

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank You For Your Input");

            if (player == 2)
            {
                player--;
                whatPlayer.setText("player2");
                return;
            }



    }
}

public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    new TicTacToe();
}   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use,

`whatPlayer.setEnabled(b)`  not `whatPlayer.setEnable(b)`